# Can not read value propertie from textarea object with Selenium Basic (VBA)

Tags: vba, selenium, textarea

I am having issues to read the "value" propertie from a textarea element in a webpage.

The odd think is that the code use to work, but it stopped, apparently, after a chromedriver/chrome update.

The code line I am using to read it is:

```
Text = Selenium.FindElementByCss("textarea[id='some_textarea_id']").Value
```

But now it returns a empty string.

In the "console" tab of Chrome I can filter the text of the textarea element using the below css selector:

```
$$("textarea[id='some_textarea_id']")[0].value
```

But in Selenium VBA I fail when I try to use:

```
Text = Selenium.FindElementByCss("textarea[id='some_textarea_id']")[0].Value
```

or

```
Text = Selenium.FindElementByCss("textarea[id='some_textarea_id']")(0).Value
```

In the first case the sintax is not accepted. The line goes red and i can't run the program.

In the second case I get the error "the object does not accept this proporty or method".

The object is like these (also odd the text I am trying to read, does not appear here):

```
<textarea class="text sr " wrap="off" id="some_textarea_id" cols="20" maxlen="15" style="top: 0px; left: 103px; width: 132px; height: 21px; background-color: rgb(222, 224, 224);" arautocak="0" arautoctt="400" rows="1" readonly=""></textarea>
```

Does any one have any clue about the cause of this problem?

Comment: Care to share the error you are getting?

Comment: @StureS sorry. I add some more information about the erros. But basically the way it worked before, now retuns a empty string. And the selector tested in chrome return the "no property or method in this object" message.

Comment: Is any selector in Selenium and VBA working?

Comment: Yes. CSS selector are working normally.

Comment: Why only the property "values" apear when I try to select the element on Chrome? Why do I have to use [0] on $$("textarea[id='some_textarea_id']")[0].value fot ir to work? Does any one have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Turns out the problem was actually the chromedriver version.

I found out I was using the wrong version.

I don't know why, but there are apparently two chrome driver sites:

1. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

and

2. https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

In the site number 1 I only get version 91.0.4472.19 of chromedriver, that seems to have the bug I describe above.

In site number 2 I got version 91.0.4472.101 that didn't present that bug.

Note: My chrome browser version is: 91.0.4472.77.

I hope this information helps some one with the same problem. And if anyone knows why there are these two sites for chromedriver download I would love to know.

Thanks